# What is the analog to Fourier Transform for the sum of normals?

Tags: normal-distribution, transformation

In electric engineering (my field) we use Fourier Transform to represent an arbitrary signal as a sum of sinusoidal signals.

I've stumbled upon a statistics problem where I want to decompose a distribution function as a sum of *normal curves*. Like the drawing bellow:

[image]

I think there is an analog to Fourier transform to this but, instead of frequency, the coefficients to be determined would be the mean and the standard deviation of each *normal component*. In the college we see a lot of links between exponentials and sinusoidals functions, which makes me think there is a missing link here that wasn't presented to me.

I don't want a lecture, just someone to point me the right direction.

Comment: The decomposition of a Fourier transform "works" because of orthogonality of components, leading to a rather explicit way to express (perhaps approximately) a function as a sum of sines and cosines.   Your normal distributions are not orthogonal in any easily discernable way, but we can think of fitting a sum of normal distributions ("Gaussians") to an input curve as a combination of linear and nonlinear optimizations.

Comment: @hardmath does it mean that each term added with the Fourier will best approximate the original function independent of the next terms, but each *gaussian component* added with this *normal decomposition* depends on all subsequent terms to be a better approximation?

Comment: Yes, depending on how you measure the "goodness" of the approximation.  Fourier series work well with a least-squares measure of "error", and the errors (residuals) after a finite number of terms are orthogonal to the preceding terms.  We don't have this nice property for Gaussian sums.  A practical approach would be to identify peaks in the signal and located Gaussian peaks at those locations.  The heights and widths of the corresponding "normals" become the unknowns that you would optimize to get the best fit.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the [Weierstrass transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform), defined by
$$ W[f](x) \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y) e^{(x-y)^2/4} \, dy. $$